# Sending text into whatever window that is currently in focus

Tags: c#, string, text

I'm trying to write a program with C# that sends text into other windows.
How do I write a command in C# that sends a text into the window that is currently under the users focus?

For example:

If the user clicks an open notepad window, or an open outlook letter, or an open excel sheet, and then clicks the button on my program, a text will be "pasted" directly into the last notepad window/outlook letter/excel cell that the user clicked on last.

I hope my question is clear enough. I'm not so experienced and am missing a lot of terminology.

Comment: Please don't add "C#" and such to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your application out of focus by minimizing or hiding the main window, and then send your text with

```
SendKeys.SendWait("Hello World!");
```

Finally, restore your main window.

---

If the code is executed in the main form, you could do this

```
this.Visible = false;
SendKeys.SendWait("Hello World!");    
this.Visible = true;
```

Comment: This works as long as the form has some kind of text control that has focus by default. If you know the application before the call you could potentially send the keys that put focus on the control. You could sent {TAB}{TAB}{TAB} or whatever.. or even CTRL or ALT combinations.

Comment: Now I have to find a way to control the management of other running programs.

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait("Hello World!");`
Sends my application into an infinite loop. I'm trying different ways to use "SendKeys" but no success... any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me. I tried three approaches, 1: `this.Visible = false; sendkeys; this.Visible = true;`, 2: `this.Hide(); sendkeys; this.Show();`, 3: `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; sendkeys; this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal`. They all work.

Comment: You must hide the application which executes the SendKeys, otherwise it will be sending the keys to itself; however, this will not work, since it is busy, beacuse it is still executing the sendkeys, which, in turn is waiting for the keys to be accepted. This creates your deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

Olivier's response actually seems more accurate (and taught me something :)) than my original "does not seem achievable". If you need an example, then take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

However, on a more complex level, without an API to call into, there is not much more that you can do beyond this solution.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I agree, but as you say with the API, if the program to insert into was part of the application there should be a way to finagle it.  But, that'd be a slightly different question.

Comment: Actually, after researching Olivier's answer, I think he is right and something new is learned by me :)

Comment: It might work, but you'd have to focus accurately on the window in the other program.  Finding the 'text field' in an application doesn't strike me as simple, though I suppose if that was the last thing it may work. Seems like it would be buggy to me though.

Comment: I totally agree, but it is semi-doable.

Comment: If you have something like Notepad open, then the text area is usually focused.

Comment: Some programs used by supporters for example, who have to use the same texts over and over again, provide a set of buttons. No matter which program I use, as long as the focus is on a text field, all I have to do is mouse-click on one of these buttons and the matching text just pops up into the text field in focus. That's what I'm trying to achieve.